# Repository not visible on github.com

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

Though I know GitHub by name since a long time. I have never made any intensive use of it.
I am now trying to get into it and learn it seriously.

Here is a question. I just used GitHub DeskTop to create a repository from a project I had and wanted to share.
I went up to "Commit to master" and everything looked fine.
But at that point when I went to github.com I was not able to see my new repository.

After a while I discovered that I had to do a "Publish" for the repository to become visible on github.com.

My question is: what is exactly the situation before the "Publish" operation?
It is on GitHub but even I cannot access it?

It may be a beginner question, but on GitHub I am a beginner.

Comment: no, it isn't in github before publish, just commit locally

Comment: OK, I see. I hadn't quite got each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be on your local only(GIT) before publishing(GITHUB).Same will happen when you add any new files to your directories, you'll first add it to index(GIT),commit it(GIT) and then push it(to GITHUB).

Well you can directly create new Repository from Github itself and then clone it to your local. This way is reverse of what you are currently doing. By default it creates readMe in that directory.

Nice tutorial on YouTube for Git: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVsySz-h9r4

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with basic GIT principles? Particularly remote and local repositories?

Github is simply a remote destination, and although you have committed, you would need to *push* these changes to a remote repository like one Github hosts. I can almost guarantee that there is no remote configured, or that if there is (and you can't see it on the site) that the `git push` would fail citing that the remote destination does not exist.